# Report Generation in Specflow

Tags: nunit, specflow

I am using specflow to create my feature files using GWT scenarios in visual studio 2015. When I use Specflow + Runner I am able to to see the report generated for the test. But I use Nunit for the execution I am not able to view report. How can I see the XML report file?

Comment: Which XML report do you mean?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Does the Nunit test Runner Produce any result report?(Specflow + Runner produce HTML report) In many websites it is mentioned as Nunit gives TestResult.XML

Comment: does any other free unit test provider other than specflow runner is available to generate html report from specflow

Answer (score 0):

Does the Nunit test Runner Produce any result report?(Specflow + Runner produce HTML report) In many websites it is mentioned as  Nunit gives TestResult.XML

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pickles](http://www.picklesdoc.com/) to create documentation for Specflow.